# Creating Tasks with timeouts

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous, timeout, task-parallel-library

I wanted to have a series of tasks being executed each with a timeout of it's own.

I borrowed the extension method for creating tasks with timeouts from here 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx

So the code is below

```
 public static Task TimeoutAfter(this Task task, int millisecondsTimeout)
        {
            // Short-circuit #1: infinite timeout or task already completed
            if (task.IsCompleted || (millisecondsTimeout == Timeout.Infinite))
            {
                // Either the task has already completed or timeout will never occur.
                // No proxy necessary.
                return task;
            }

            // tcs.Task will be returned as a proxy to the caller
            TaskCompletionSource<VoidTypeStruct> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<VoidTypeStruct>();

            // Short-circuit #2: zero timeout
            if (millisecondsTimeout == 0)
            {
                // We've already timed out.
                tcs.SetException(new TimeoutException());
                return tcs.Task;
            }

            // Set up a timer to complete after the specified timeout period
            Timer timer = new Timer(state =>
            {
                // Recover your state information
                var myTcs = (TaskCompletionSource<VoidTypeStruct>)state;
                // Fault our proxy with a TimeoutException
                myTcs.TrySetException(new TimeoutException());
            }, tcs, millisecondsTimeout, Timeout.Infinite);

            // Wire up the logic for what happens when source task completes
            task.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
                                {
                                    timer.Dispose(); // Cancel the timer
                                    MarshalTaskResults(antecedent, tcs); // Marshal results to proxy
                                },
                                CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);

            return tcs.Task;
        }

public class Program
    {
        private static List<int> Output = new List<int>();

        private static Random _random = new Random();
        public static void LongRunningTask(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.WriteLine("Managed thread Id " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);            
            //Simulate a long running task
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            var number = _random.Next();
            Console.WriteLine("Adding " + number);
            Output.Add(number);
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task1"),TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent).TimeoutAfter(10);
            var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task2"),TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task3"),TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            tasks.Add(t1);
            tasks.Add(t2);
            tasks.Add(t3);

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an exception");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Output :");
            Output.ForEach(_ => Console.WriteLine(_));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }



the output 

    Entering task1
    Managed thread Id 10
    Entering task2
    Managed thread Id 11
    Entering task3
    Managed thread Id 14
    Adding 453738994
    Adding 156432981
    Adding 1340619865
    There was an exception
    The operation has timed out.
    Output :
    453738994
    156432981
    1340619865
```

Now, what I can't understand is why is the t1 still finishing even though I have specified a timeout and the timeout exception has occurred.

I am using .net 4.

Edit :

Ensuring that the timed out task doesn't do anything after the timeout period i.e. cancelling the task altogether.

```
public class Program
    {
        private static List<int> Output = new List<int>();

        private static Random _random = new Random();
        public static int LongRunningTask(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            Console.WriteLine("Managed thread Id " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);            
            //Simulate a long running task
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            var number = _random.Next();
            Console.WriteLine("Adding " + number + " From thread  - " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            return number;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In Main");
            Console.WriteLine("Managed thread Id " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var tasks = new List<Task>();

            var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task1"), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
                                 .ContinueWith(_ => Output.Add(_.Result),cts.Token)
                                 .TimeoutAfter(1000);
            var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task2"), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
                                 .ContinueWith(_ => Output.Add(_.Result));
            var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task3"), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
                                 .ContinueWith(_ => Output.Add(_.Result));

            tasks.Add(t1);
            tasks.Add(t2);
            tasks.Add(t3);

            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an exception");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                cts.Cancel();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Output :");
            Output.ForEach(_ => Console.WriteLine(_));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Output :

```
In Main
Managed thread Id 9
Entering task1
Managed thread Id 10
Entering task2
Managed thread Id 11
Entering task3
Managed thread Id 13
Adding 1141027730 From thread  - 10
Adding 1856518562 From thread  - 13
Adding 1856518562 From thread  - 11
There was an exception
The operation has timed out.
Output :
1141027730
1856518562
1856518562
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output contains three values, because the program waits all tasks `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());` and Output is common field (because closure)

You can remain only first task and you'll see another result

```
Entering task1
Managed thread Id 10
There was an exception
The operation has timed out.
Output :
Adding 1923041190
Managed thread Id 10
```

Please note, that `Adding` has called, but the number is absent in the `Output`. `Adding` was called because `LongRunningTask` works in this Task `Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task1"), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)` and Exception has been thrown on the different thread. This exception doesn't effect on `LongRunningTask`

**Edit:**

There several choices:

1. Call `t1.Wait` the exception'll be re-thrown immediately and you can cancel task
2. Call `TimeoutAfter(10)` before ContinueWith

   ```
       var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningTask("Entering task1"))
                            .TimeoutAfter(10)
                            .ContinueWith(_=> Output.Add(_.Result), cts.Token);
   ```

`Continue` will be executed only after completed `TimeoutAfter` and `LongRunningTask`, but you have to update `TimeoutAfter`, you've to return `Task<Result>` not `Task`

```
    public static Task<Result> TimeoutAfter<Result>(this Task<Result> task, int millisecondsTimeout)
    {
        // Short-circuit #1: infinite timeout or task already completed
        if (task.IsCompleted || (millisecondsTimeout == Timeout.Infinite))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("task.IsCompleted");
            // Either the task has already completed or timeout will never occur.
            // No proxy necessary.
            return task;
        }
        // tcs.Task will be returned as a proxy to the caller
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();

        // Short-circuit #2: zero timeout
        if (millisecondsTimeout == 0)
        {
            //                Console.WriteLine("millisecondsTimeout == 0");
            // We've already timed out.
            tcs.SetException(new TimeoutException());
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        // Set up a timer to complete after the specified timeout period
        var timer = new Timer(state => tcs.TrySetException(new TimeoutException()), null, millisecondsTimeout, Timeout.Infinite);

        // Wire up the logic for what happens when source task completes
        task.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
            {
                timer.Dispose();
                MarshalTaskResults(antecedent, tcs); 
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: How can I tell the task to stop executing once the timeout has occured, so that it doesn't add anything to the output while running in the background. Supplying it with the cancellation token source and then cancelling that doesn't work.

Comment: In the code only `Task.WaitAll` re-throws TimoutException, all tasks already completed and `cts.Cancel()` doesn't matter. Put `cts.Cancel()` before `Task.WaitAll` and the task'll be canced

Comment: Which would cancel the task irrespective of the timeout..the behaviour I want is to cancel the task in case of a timeout or exception.

Comment: Very important to note that TimeoutAfter won't kill the task in any way. LongRunningTask will always execute to completion, regardless of whether the timeout is triggered or not. See example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dny3c1

Answer (score 2):

The `TimeoutAfter()` method doesn't do anything to the underlying `Task`. So, even if timeout occurs, the `Task` still continues executing and will eventually complete.

There is no good way to fix that without modifying `LongRunningTask()`. If you can modify `LongRunningTask()`, then what you should do is to make it accept `CancellationToken` and check it at appropriate points.

Your `ContinueWith()` attempt didn't change anything, because the `Task` still completed, so the continuation fired.

What would help is something like:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongRunningTask("Entering task1"))
                     .TimeoutAfter(1000)
                     .ContinueWith(t => Output.Add(t.Result), cts.Token);
```

If you do this, then `t1` will represent the continuation and so it will be faulted if the timeout occurs (and waiting on it will throw an exception). If you don't want that, check the state of `t` in the continuation before accessing its `Result`.

Also, you should never call `Add()` on a `List` like this, because `Add()` is not thread-safe and there is a chance that multiple threads will try adding to it at the same time. To avoid that, either use one of the concurrent collections or locking.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference sake,
I ended up doing something like this

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => LongRunningTask("Entering task1"),                              TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
                                     .TimeoutAfter(1000)
                                     .ContinueWith(_ =>
                                {
                                    if(!(_.IsCanceled || _.IsFaulted))
                                        Output.Add(_.Result);
                                }
                                , cts.Token);
```

Comment: BTW, I think you should use `_` only when you *don't* use the parameter. If you do use it, it should be something like `antecedent`, `task` or at least `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I find the previous answer to be find, I have a implementation that I find quite easy to implement with my event based framework.

Let me explain the requirement, I have to wrap all in async that could take longer than 50 MS so that user interactions with the screen stays fluid. All my socket requests and response to the server therefore need to be wrapped. these type of programming typical involves requesting something and then getting an answer the requests and answers do not need to follow FIFO as one can ask, what's the price of gold and get the data flowing in several hundred times per second and then ask what's my accounts value.

Here is my implementation, I added some comments making it easier for some to follow.

```
internal Task<string[]> RequestAccountNamesAsync() => RequestAccountNamesAsync(-1);
internal Task<string[]> RequestAccountNamesAsync(int millisecondsTimeout) => RequestAccountNamesAsync(CancellationToken.None, millisecondsTimeout);
internal Task<string[]> RequestAccountNamesAsync(CancellationToken token,int millisecondsTimeout = 1000 )
{

    var t1 =  Task.Factory.StartNew<string[]>( () =>
    {
        try
        {
            //the result type of the Task
            string[] result = null;

            //local helper function used to hookup the event
            void Method(object sender, OnAccountsReceivedArgs ac)
            {
                this.OnAccountsReceived -= Method;
                result = ac.Accounts;
            }

            //event responsible for reacting on the "on complete event"
            this.OnAccountsReceived += Method;



            //item responsible for initiating the socket request
            clientSocket.reqManagedAccts();

            //measure time-out 
            DateTimeOffset startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            //loop waiting for the result to come from the server
            while (result == null)
            {
                if (millisecondsTimeout > 0 && DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(startTime).Milliseconds >= millisecondsTimeout)
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                //if the value of the millisecondsTimeout argument is zero, the thread relinquishes the remainder of its 
                // time slice to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run
                // If there are no other threads of equal priority that are ready to run, execution of the current thread
                // is not suspended. 
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                    
            //integrate my proprietary logging framework
            logger.Enqueue<IBClient>(e);
            throw e;
        }
    });

    return t1;

}
```

Comment: My methods are internal as they are not callable from outside the application.